# DOMDocument::$documentElement must not be accessed before initialization

Tags: php, drupal-9

I've updated my drupal environment php 7.4 to php 8.1.18. i've enable some extensions, but I have this error when i try to download a PDF

```
Error : Typed property DOMDocument::$documentElement must not be accessed before initialization in Masterminds\HTML5\Parser\DOMTreeBuilder->startTag() (/var/www/myproject/vendor/masterminds/html5/src/HTML5/Parser/DOMTreeBuilder.php line 275)

#0 /var/www/myproject/vendor/masterminds/html5/src/HTML5/Parser/Tokenizer.php(399): Masterminds\HTML5\Parser\DOMTreeBuilder->startTag()
#1 /var/www/myproject/vendor/masterminds/html5/src/HTML5/Parser/Tokenizer.php(141): Masterminds\HTML5\Parser\Tokenizer->tagName()
#2 /var/www/myproject/vendor/masterminds/html5/src/HTML5/Parser/Tokenizer.php(82): Masterminds\HTML5\Parser\Tokenizer->consumeData()
#3 /var/www/myproject/vendor/masterminds/html5/src/HTML5.php(161): Masterminds\HTML5\Parser\Tokenizer->parse()
#4 /var/www/myproject/vendor/masterminds/html5/src/HTML5.php(89): Masterminds\HTML5->parse()
#5 /var/www/myproject/vendor/dompdf/dompdf/src/Dompdf.php(478): Masterminds\HTML5->loadHTML()
#6 /var/www/myproject/web/modules/contrib/entity_print/src/Plugin/EntityPrint/PrintEngine/DomPdf.php(207): Dompdf\Dompdf->loadHtml()
```

the extensions are the same than PHP7.4

[image]

I'm using it with drupal 9

Comment: Moderators at strike https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389811/moderation-strike-stack-overflow-inc-cannot-consistently-ignore-mistreat-an - so I also will not do **any** (further) content/curation-related action here